# Increment a nullable column in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with nullable column.

```
create table testgt(retrycount number(3));
```

I have to update for the following cases.

If the value is null I should update as 0

and if the value is not null I should increment by 1.

Can a single query handle this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `coalesce()`:

```
update testgr
    set retrycount = coalesce(retrycount + 1, 0);
```